# cUrl unable to login to a remote site

Tags: php, curl

I have coded for login to a remote site using `CURL with PHP` but after getting the response I'm getting a message from website that `Your browsers cookie functionality is turned off. Please turn it on.` However the cookies are enabled and browser login to site is working.

Below is my code that i have coded :

```
function __construct($forum_url,$username,$password){
        if(!function_exists('curl_init')){
            trigger_error('api_chrono::error, Sorry but it appears that CURL is not loaded, Please install it to continue.');
            return false;
        }   

        if(empty($forum_url)){
            trigger_error('api_chrono::error, The forum location is required to continue, Please edit your script.');
            return false;
        }
        $this->forum_url = $forum_url;
        $this->cookie_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'cookies/'.md5($forum_url).'.txt';
        $this->deleteCookie();
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->FetchPage();
    }
private function FetchPage(){
        $this->curl = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL,$this->forum_url); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,$this->forum_url); 
        $page = curl_exec($this->curl);
        include('ganon.php');
        $dom = str_get_dom($page);
        $this->continueTo = $dom('input[name="continueTo"]',0)->getAttribute('value');
        $this->changeLogInPermanentlyPref = $dom('input[name="changeLogInPermanentlyPref"]',0)->getAttribute('value');
        $this->_sourcePage = $dom('input[name="_sourcePage"]',0)->getAttribute('value');
        $this->__fp = $dom('input[name="__fp"]',0)->getAttribute('value');  
    }

    public function login(){
        $postdata = "email=".$this->username."&password=".$this->password."&logInPermanently=1&continueTo=".$this->continueTo."&_sourcePage=".$this->_sourcePage."&
        __fp=".$this->__fp."&login=Login";

        //$this->curl = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL,$this->forum_url); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt ($this->curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$this->cookie_path); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$this->cookie_path); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_REFERER,$this->forum_url); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
        curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST,1); 
        echo $page = curl_exec($this->curl);

        //curl_setopt($this->curl,CURLOPT_URL,'www.chrono24.com/en/dealer-area/index.htm'); 
        //echo curl_exec($this->curl);

        //Error handling
        if(curl_errno($this->curl)){
            $this->error = array(
                curl_errno($this->curl),
                curl_error($this->curl),
            );
            curl_close($this->curl);
            return $this->error;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

FetchPage() is calling first via constructor for fetching all hidden and unique values, and after that login() function is calling up.

class param : 
forum_url = https://www.chrono24.com/en/user/login.htm
username = ravi.soni@ideavate.com
pwd : test123I

Any help should be very appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login page will set some cookies that you have to send with every request. So you have to set the cookiejar and -file also in `FetchPage`.